# Android Library Project - Error when calling context.getResources().openRawResource()

Tags: android, android-resources, library-project

I'm developing an android library project that should read from an xml file in its raw resources (let's call it xml_file_name.myextension).

What I do is basically  creating a jar file of the library project including these folders:

- src
- gen
- lib
- res/raw

and referencing it as a library in a test app. This is the code that I use (inside the library project) in order to get the xml file:

```
int xml_res_id = -1;

for (Field f : R.raw.class.getFields()) {

  System.out.println("Raw resource found: " + f.getName());
  if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("xml_file_name"))
    xml_res_id = f.getInt(null);

}

if(xml_res_id != -1){
  System.out.println("xml_file_id: " + xml_res_id);
  InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(xml_res_id);
  // Decode xml file with SAXParser..
}
```

(I have the app context because the app explicitly passes it to the library project.)

What happens is that when I launch the test app (and call the method that reads the xml file) I get this error:

[image: Android Console Error]

It seems that the xml file is actually in the right folder, because:

1) The for loop actually prints "Raw resource found: xml_file_name.myextension" and "xml_file_id: 2130968576"

2) If I put a file named "xml_file_name.myextension" in the res/raw folder of the app, it does not compile, and the error is: "Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: res/raw/xml_file_name.myextension". This basically gives me the proof that the 
file is correctly "imported" from the library project.

Please Note:
I also tried in this other way

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xml_file_name);
```

getting the same error.

I honestly don't understand what could be the problem.. what am I doing wrong?

---

### Edit:

for anyone interested in this issue:
I finally realized that this is not possible, basically because when I try to get a resource through context.anymethod I refer to the R file of the app, so I can't give the resource ID got from the R file of my library project.

It will compile, because the library project jar file contains the resource (R.raw.xml_file), but the call to context.something will always give null as a result because it refers to the app R file, that does not have that particular resource in it.

I finally had to put my xml file in the res/raw folder of the app, and access the xml_file raw resource in this way:

```
int xml_id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("xml_file_name", "raw", context.getPackageName());

// Getting input stream from xml file
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(xml_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done this with success - the library object should be within the app context.  However, it only works with `Activity` and no other type that I have found.  Using the same library with a `FragmentActivity` fails with `NoClassDefFoundError`.

**EDIT******

It may work with a FragmentActivity within the same root namespace as the library.  I was accessing from a different root namespace.

**END EDIT******

I have a library project that references an xml file:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.application_table_defs);
```

when I call the library method that executes the previous line I have to pass in a context:

```
Context context = this.getContext();
```

The key is fully qualifying the `getResource` to `context.getResources()...` that was injected.